# How can I successfully translate NB-IoT cellIDs with Google Geolocation API?

Tags: api, geolocation

Does Google Gelocation support NB-IoT towers?

Google's [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/requests-geolocation#cell_tower_object) does not explicitly mention NB-IoT cellID locations.  So far have not had any luck at either opencellid.org or google gelocation API with getting cellIDs translated to coordinates.

Here an example location message.  Confirmed from 2 different systems so let's assume for a moment there are no typos/mistakes in the raw message itself.
[raw message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJbK.png)

Here the translated google API message in postman.  Note the google API is not very clear on what the "radioType" should be for NB-IoT, does it fall under 4G (LTE) or 5G (nb-IoT)?.  I have tried all of them for this example (gsm, nr etc) and none have worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEBzO.png)

Has anyone gotten any NB-IoT cellIDs translated succesfully on googles API?  If so, what's the correct radiotype to be used?

Are there other sources that better handle these towers from LPWA sources like NB-IoT & LTE-M?

Regards
Schwizer